# Converting high chart to image and send to server using ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, image, highcharts

I need to export multiple charts to the server with the ajax call and store it as a pdf. 
I render multiple charts in a single page using different containers. I need to convert them as images and send them to the server and export them to a single pdf to be saved on the server. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

See this post: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10463

And: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=9239

Setting up server side exporting is bit of a mess. Lots of ducks to get in a row before it will work.